# What is the meaning of "in literal terms"

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology

https://www.guru99.com/java-strings.html

A string ***in literal terms*** is a series of characters.

What is the meaning of "in literal terms"? What can be used instead of that phrase. Please answer with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *literally*:

> A string, **literally**, is a series of characters.

Compare this with the expression **in simple terms** which **in literal terms** is just a variant of:

> A string, **in simple terms**, is just a series of characters.
>
> A string is **simply** a series of characters.

Although it's positioned slightly differently in the sentence for the purposes of making it sound more smoothly, the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: I believe you're sort of off the mark when you say *in simple terms* is just a variant of *in literal terms*. I mean, they're similar but it's not quite a variant – it's something completely different. Furthermore, *in literal terms* is not that common at all, so it's hardly a variant in that sense either. *In literal terms* means "literally". In this case, the author is mistaken as *string* doesn't literally mean a sequence of characters in common parlance, anyway (that's more of a technical meaning used in computer science).

Comment: I think Michael hits very close to the mark with **simple** here, though I would say **simplest**.

Answer (score 1):

The word **literal** in computing is used literally, but in general conversation **literal** is used figuratively, even though its general meaning is "not figurative".  :)

**literal** in this narrow technical sense means "consisting of letters".

The author might be playing on this.

"A literal string" aka "a string literal" in computing refers to a series of letters (i.e. characters).

`abcde` is a "string" that consists of the literals `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`.

So we might paraphrase **literal** there as **raw**.

> In raw terms, a string is a series of characters.

And thus **simplest** would be a decent paraphrase too.

> In simplest terms, a string is a series of characters.

Comment: While I think you're raising some valid points, I think you may be reading a bit too much into this. You might want to take into consideration that the author most likely isn't a native speaker of English and, while entirely possible, they're probably not making a sort of pun you're suggesting on *string literals*. Further, a *string literal* in Java (as per [*The Java Language Specification* (SE7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)) is defined as "[consisting] of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes." I wouldn't deviate from that definition.

Comment: **quite some more** is probably a good indication that the author is not English or American. But that doesn't mean that the author is unaware that **literal** means something different in computing than it does generally. And I said "computing" not "java", so that "definition" in SE7 is not relevant.  It's also not a definition but an instruction about  how to represent a string literal in source code.